# %f vs %F in PHP printf()

Tags: php, printf

Relatively new to PHP
I am trying to understand the difference between %f and %F type selectors in printf()/sprintf() functions.

The documentations says the following:
f specifier - The argument is treated as a float and presented as a floating-point number (locale aware).
F specifier - The argument is treated as a float and presented as a floating-point number (non-locale aware). Available as of PHP 5.0.3.

What are these local aware/non-local aware mean? Could you please provide any examples? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: local aware: number formatting will be shown as per local basis (like some local having , separated representation of numbers while some other have . based)

Comment: @AlivetoDie let me see if I get you right: local aware means according to local configuration (is it based on php version or smth else?) and example is that float numbers may be represented using , (like 3,1) or using . (like 3.1).   If I get you right, what about the non-local aware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%f` is locale aware. That means that its output depends on the locale setting.

You can compare it with this snippet:

```php
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE"); 

echo sprintf("%f", 1.25) . PHP_EOL; // outputs "1,250000"
echo sprintf("%F", 1.25);           // outputs "1.250000"
```

The first one will use a *comma* as decimal separator (as used in German locale). The latter will use the english/international notation.

Comment: Could we say that, whenever the formatted value is going to be used in any arithmetic ops in PHP, we should actually always use the `F` - since having the `5 + 1,2` instead of `5 + 1.2` won't ever properly work in PHP?

Comment: Yes, I'd say so.